# Java access value of a subclass variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the value of a subclass variable but don't know how to do it. It returns the super class attribute `0` because `d` is obviously of Type `Shape`. How could I access the correct value of the instance (`3`) without changing the class type of `d`? Is it possible?

```
public class Testclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape d = new Triangle(); 
        System.out.println(d.corners);;
    }
}

class Shape{
    int corners = 0;
}

class Triangle extends Shape{
    int corners = 3;
}

class Square extends Shape{
    int corners = 4;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend making the Shape class into an interface.

Comment: You should not hide attributes of a super-class within sub-classes (which is exactly what you are doing) to avoid the exact problems you have now. Take a look at [Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), this should solve your problem

Comment: ok I didn't learn about them yet. If thats the way to go that probably answers the question.

Comment: @Ben See my answer below for an example that uses a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shape{
    int corners = 0;
}

class Triangle extends Shape{
    int corners = 3;
}

class Square extends Shape{
    int corners = 4;
}
```

This creates **three different variables with the same name**. Instead, you should declare the variable once in `Shape`:

```
class Shape{
    int corners;
}
```

Now set its value in the constructor of each subclass. For example

```
class Triangle extends Shape{
    public Triangle() {
        corners = 3;
    }
}
```

Repeat for each subclass.

Answer (score -1):

The `d` field is defined twice.
The compiler relies on the declared type as it accesses to the field.
As the variable is declared `Shape`, the field defined in `Shape` is used here :

```
System.out.println(d.corners);
```

You can cast it to `Triangle` to access to the `d` field defined in Triangle :

```
System.out.println(((Triangle)d).corners);
```

But a much better way is not duplicating a field in a subclass a field that is defined in a class and visible by the subclass.
Shadowing variables is a error prone approach for developers that manipulate them.

If you need to declare the same field in the class and the subclass, which one of the class should be private and not directly accessible to the subclass but could if required provide an access to with a getter.